Guidance on how to create a pose graph dataset with a camera, IMU, and apriltags
I'm trying to create a pose graph file in g2o format for data in SE3 format. This will contain:

VERTEX_SE3:QUAT as described here. This represents each pose as SE3 (ID, x, y, z, qx, qy, qz, qw), where ID in my case would be the timestamp derived from ROS2 message timestamps in epoch clock.
EDGE_SE3:QUAT. This isn't described in the link above, but it represents an edge between two nodes by a measurement that makes them maximally overlap (e.g. matching keyframes via visual measurements). It also contains the information matrix of the pose.

The way I'm trying to capture the data is by running a turtlebot3 equipped with a realsense d435i camera. I'm planning to use the onboard odometry of the turtlebot with the /odom topic to get poses for VERTEX_SE3 as mentioned above, and then capturing apriltags with the camera and matching keyframes to derive the EDGE_SE3 measurements. The issue is that the timestamps between odometry and camera measurements probably won't match, so I can't exactly relate the vertices to edges. Therefore, I think the only solution is to use a visual odometry algorithm to get odometry and also for measurements using apriltags as this way, the timestamps in measurements would match a frame used in odometry. The issue is limited computing power on the microcontroller, which is a Raspberry Pi Model 3B+ in this case, which can only capture RGB images on the d435i at 15FPS. I also think if I use a VO algorithm, the vertices are already too accurate and the data will be easy to optimize with any algorithm.
I'm unfamiliar with exactly how to make pose graph datasets, especially in g2o format. I've read the g2o paper and there are datasets, such as from here. In that same link, they mention the Intel dataset was captured with wheel odometry and laser range finder so I'm assuming different sensors can be used to capture vertices/edges and properly relate their timestamps.
So my main questions/problems are:

I can't find exactly how to properly create these datasets and would appreciate any guidance on how to proceed to make a good dataset with a robot with a camera/IMU in an environment with apriltags. Although the g2o documentation explains how to use the library in C++, I didn't find any information anywhere about how to create these .g2o files.
Would matching keyframes of the same apriltag with visual features be a good way to get measurements for the edges? I already have the poses of the apriltag relative to the camera frame, so I assume I just have to find relative poses between the same apriltag in two frames to get relative poses of the two nodes that observe those frames to get the edge?
What are good values for the information matrix? Should it be the inverse of the covariance matrix, or does it heavily depend on this context (relative measurements via images)?

Thanks

Do you already know the positions of the april tags in a map frame, or are you trying to calculate the positions of the tags?

The pose of the april tags are known with respect to the camera frame via the /tf topic in the apriltag ROS2 library. As I'm still unsure of the odometry source to use, I don't know if this can get the pose of the tags in a single global frame.
